# Exception Thrown by Spring Jpa Repository not getting caught in Exception Handler @Controller Advice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

Below is my ExceptionHandler Class in Spring boot

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class CustomResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {


@ExceptionHandler({InvalidRequestException.class, PropertyReferenceException.class})
public final ResponseEntity<ExceptionDetails> handleInvalidRequestException(InvalidRequestException ex, WebRequest request) {
    ExceptionDetails details = new ExceptionDetails(ex.getMessage(),request.getDescription(false), new Date());
    return new ResponseEntity<ExceptionDetails>(details, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

}
```

}

Now below is the code in my service class.

```
@Override
public Page<Segment> listSegment(int pageNum, int size, String sortBy, String direction, String app) {
        log.info("Starting to query the segment list");
        Pageable pageable = createPageRequest(size, pageNum, sortBy, direction);
        Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(page, size, dir, sortBy);
        Page<Segment> resultPage = segmentRepository.findByApp(app,pageable);
        if(pageNum > resultPage.getTotalPages() || resultPage.getContent().isEmpty()) {
            log.info("No segment present");
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("No Segment Present");
        }

        log.info("Total segment successfully fetched is: "+resultPage.getContent().size());
        if(resultPage.hasNext())
            return new Page<>(resultPage.getContent(), true);
        else
            return new Page<>(resultPage.getContent());
    }
```

In `sortBy` if I pass an invalid Column Name then this throws `PropertyReferenceException` which is not getting caught in my ExceptionHandler as code provided above and I don't know why.

But if I catch this exception using a try-catch block in my Service layer and throw my Custom `InvalidRequestException` then this gets caught in exception handler.

Can please someone let me know the reason and how I can catch `PropertyReferenceException` in my ExceptionHandler

Comment: Post code properly formatted as code, not as quoted text, and post the exact and complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Hi @JBNizet, I have updated it

Comment: Could you post code of your Custom Exception?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is mismatch between your this line - `@ExceptionHandler({InvalidRequestException.class, PropertyReferenceException.class})` & method signature `handleInvalidRequestException(InvalidRequestException ex, WebRequest request)` .

You are annotating this method to handle two exceptions but in method argument specifying only one & that exception is a very specific exception so its getting called for `InvalidRequestException` . Method argument needs to be a parent class of both exceptions if you wish both to be matched to same method.

You either need to change method as answered by slimane or have two handler methods - one for each exception.

`@ExceptionHandler({InvalidRequestException.class}) handleInvalidRequestException(InvalidRequestException ex, WebRequest request)`

&

`@ExceptionHandler({PropertyReferenceException.class}) handlePropertyReferenceException(PropertyReferenceException ex, WebRequest request)`